# Scanner method 'nextLine()' skips an input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

OK, So I have this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Library
{

    int Acc_Num;
    String Title;
    String Author;

    public void input()
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Your Accession Number");
        Acc_Num = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter The Title Of The Book");
        Title = s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter The Author Of The Book");
        Author = s.next();
    }

    public void compute()
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Number Of Days Late");
        int Day_Late = s.nextInt();

        int Fine = 2 * Day_Late;

        System.out.println("Fine: " + Fine);
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Accession Number\t\tTitle\t\tAuthor");
        System.out.println(Acc_Num + "\t\t" + Title + "\t\t" + Author);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Library Mem1 = new Library();
        Mem1.input();
        Mem1.compute();
        Mem1.display();

    }

}
```

The thing is, when it goes into the function to get input, it take input for Title but not for author. Have attached a screenshot of the program running in cmd.
Would love to have this solved.
Is this a Scanner glitch? Or Am I doing something wrong?[image]